# Prestashop - Problem with cart quantity update in header

Tags: php, module, prestashop, cart

I made a module where I need to get or create the Cart object to add the product in the shopping cart.

On "Add to shopping cart" action, if context has already a Cart created, I call this cart and the "1" next to the shopping cart icon appears instantly when I add the product.

```php
if ($this->context->cookie->id_cart){
    $cart = $this->context->cart;
    $cart->my_custom_field = Tools::getValue('svgTemplateResult'); // Here I add a value to a new field I made
    $cart->update();
}

// Update the shopping cart
$cart->updateQty(1, $this->getProductId(), $id_product_attribute = null, $id_customization = false, $operator = 'up', $id_address_delivery = 0, $shop = null, $auto_add_cart_rule = true);
```

[image]

If there is no Cart in the context, I need to create it like I saw somewhere :

```php
if ($cart->id == null){
    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->id_customer = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_customer);
    $cart->id_address_delivery = (int)  (Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId($cart->id_customer));
    $cart->id_address_invoice = $cart->id_address_delivery;
    $cart->id_lang = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_lang);
    $cart->id_currency = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_currency);
    $cart->id_carrier = 1;
    $cart->recyclable = 0;
    $cart->gift = 0;
    $cart->add();
    $cart->my_custom_field = Tools::getValue('svgTemplateResult'); // Here I add a value to a new field I made
    $cart->update();
    $this->context->cookie->id_cart = (int)($cart->id);  
}

// Update the shopping cart
$cart->updateQty(1, $this->getProductId(), $id_product_attribute = null, $id_customization = false, $operator = 'up', $id_address_delivery = 0, $shop = null, $auto_add_cart_rule = true);
```

But the "1" does not appears instantly next to the shopping cart icon. I need to refresh the page to see it appear.

If I don't refresh the page but I click another time on "Add to shopping cart" button, it instantly refresh the number (because the Cart is in the context so we go first option) and I have 2 times the product in the shopping cart.

What can I do with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to refresh the cart icon with a JS AJAX call,
just check / reproduce in your module what is normally happening when you click the 'ADD TO CART' button from a product page.

You'll see an ajax call to the **ps_shoppingcart** front controller:

```
/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax
```

Payload is pretty basic :

```
id_customization: 0
id_product: {id_product}
id_product_attribute: {id_product_attribute}
action: add-to-cart
```

Otherwise with "pure" PHP your only choice is to refresh the page after every cart modification by using **Tools::redirect()**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the delay, I was on holiday :)
I can see I badly explained my problem. My module doesn't use AJAX to update the cart icon. The 'ADD TO CART' button refresh the page, that's how the controller's function is called. But even with the refresh, the first time I add the product to a non existing cart in the context, the icon stay at '0', if I refresh again I can see the '1'.
After that, the 'ADD TO CART' will update correctly the cart icon '2', '3', '4' etc..

Comment: If the cart exist in the context (it has been created before) and is also empty. The 'ADD TO CART' button will as usual refresh the page and the '1' will appears as expected this time.

Comment: I just found a solution, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I simply had to create the cart in the context (if there wasn't one already) BEFORE clicking on "Add to shopping cart", so in the
`public function initContent()` of the front controller of the module for example.